# Select menu closes once you click on it

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, html-select

I create a `<select>` menu using Javascript then attach it to the page. But when I click on it, it closes immediately.

Here's my code, I'm stumpped.

```
var accounts = [
    ['user1', 'password'],
    ['user2', 'passowrd']
]

function html(){
    var button = '<a href="#" id="switchacc">Switch User</a>&nbsp;• &nbsp;';
    $('a[href=search.php]')[0].before(button);

    $('#switchacc').click(function(){
        $(this).html('<select id="accounts">'+ accountss +'</select>');
        return false;
    });


    var accountss = '';
    for(i = 0; i <= accounts.length; i++){
        accountss = accountss + '<option name="' + accounts[i][0] + '" value="' + i + '">' + accounts[i][0] + '</option>';
    }   
}
html();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you embedding your `select` in that `a` link? See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meLpV/) for an example. You cannot embed a list in a link.